# getting error Could not send email in cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp, cakephp-2.0

I've been trying to send emails with Pear on xampp through Gmail, and after spending hours setting it all up and figuring out all the errors I was getting, I thought I was so close, until I started getting this error:
controller action

```
 public function automail() {
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $ret_msg = null;
    try {

        $is_call_email = true;
        $subject = "case detail";
        $comment = "Ready to Review";
        $email_to = "exmaple@gmail.com";

        if ($is_call_email == true) {
            $email_to = str_replace(' ', '', $email_to);
            $email_addresses = preg_split('/[;,]/', $email_to);

            $this->log($is_call_email,'bool');
            $email = new CakeEmail();                         
            $email->from(array($this->Session->read('Auth.User.email') => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name')))                
                    ->to($email_addresses)                
                      ->subject($subject)                        
                        ->send($comment);
            $this->log($subject,'subject');
        } 
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $ret_msg = $ex->getMessage();
        $this->log($ex->getLine(), 'emailError');
    }

    $this->log('Return msg is  = ' . $ret_msg, 'shared');
    return;
```

in email.php

```
<?php 
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'example@gmail.com', //example@gmail.com
        'password' => 'secret',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('exampe@gmail.com' => 'Nam Email'),
        'log' => true
    );

}
```

from and to both are same email addresses because i was send in my account for testing...
please help me or any advice for how to send email using cakephp....

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `$email->config`. Like:

```
$email->config('default')
      ->from(array($this->Session->read('Auth.User.email') => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name')))                
      ->to($email_addresses)                
      ->subject($subject)                        
      ->send($comment);
```